# Dialogflow fulfillment using HTTP responses

Tags: database, azure, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have an azure function that gets json and returns json.
I want that upon intent being invoked on dialogflow, the function will be called and the response will be shown to the user. Because I'm using multiple intents, I can't put it simply in the webhook because I don't want the same logic for every intent.
I've tried to use the Inline editor and upon intent to make an HTTP request to my Azure function. However, whenever I tried using JavaScript library for HTTP ( Ajax 
 etc.. ) the Inline editor didn't recognize the library
If anyoune has an example of how to make HTTP Post Request with json parameters this would be a great help !

Comment: Can you update your question to include your code, the package.json, and any errors that you may be encountering? https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/hey-google-i-need-help-with-my-action-8cf09714a20d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED - if anyone else comes across this problem, make sure your Azure function returns Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2 . This way it matches the DialogFlow and he can understand your response easily :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add a library to the Dialogflow Inline Editor, you can click on the "package.json" tab and edit it to include the npm specification for the package you wish to include.

[image]

Comment: Well that's what I tried. However, using the library in the index.js using require emit an error that the package doesn't exist